# /tmp/tomcat-docbase is always created with a Spring Boot JAR (but not a WAR)

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

From STS I'm creating a standard Spring Boot 1.5.2 'Web' project.  If you run this application you get two directories created - the normal 'base' directory and a 'tomcat-docbase' directory

```
. . .  4096 Mar 29 10:00 tomcat.2743776473678691880.8080
. . .  4096 Mar 29 10:00 tomcat-docbase.76291847886629412.8080
```

If I change this project to a WAR project I get only the 'base' directory

```
. . .   4096 Mar 29 10:06 tomcat.3131223012454570991.8080
```

It's easy to override the default base directory using

```
 server.tomcat.basedir=.
```

however this has no effect on tomcat-docbase.  It is possible to override tomcat-docbase programmatically but seems like a hack.

Does anyone think this is a bug?

Answer (score 11):

Solution:
create a folder name as ***public*** under your project, in the same folder with your JAR.

Reason:
from the springboot code, there is no configuration for docbase folder.
but you can create a common root folder in you project folder name as *public*, *static* or *src/main/webapp*, then the springboot will never create temp tomcat-docbase folder for you again.

```
private static final String[] COMMON_DOC_ROOTS = { "src/main/webapp", "public", "static" }
...
public final File getValidDirectory() {
    File file = this.directory;
    file = (file != null ? file : getWarFileDocumentRoot());
    file = (file != null ? file : getExplodedWarFileDocumentRoot());
    file = (file != null ? file : getCommonDocumentRoot());
    if (file == null && this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logNoDocumentRoots();
    }
    else if (this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        this.logger.debug("Document root: " + file);
    }
    return file;
}
...
private File getCommonDocumentRoot() {
    for (String commonDocRoot : COMMON_DOC_ROOTS) {
        File root = new File(commonDocRoot);
        if (root.exists() && root.isDirectory()) {
            return root.getAbsoluteFile();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Link: [DocumentRoot.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/server/DocumentRoot.java)

Comment: Correct link: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/server/DocumentRoot.java (I think)

Answer (score 2):

For Spring Boot 2.x+

```
@Component
public class EmbeddedServletContainerConfig implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {

    @Override
    public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        factory.setDocumentRoot(new File("/your/path/here"));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a programmatically way of setting the docbase folder with spring and the embedded tomcat server. You must override the `TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` implementation like the following:

```
public @Bean EmbeddedServletContainerFactory embeddedServletContainerFactory() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory("/app", 8080) {
        @Override
        protected void configureContext(Context context, ServletContextInitializer[] initializers) {
            context.setDocBase("/path/to/your/docbase");
            super.configureContext(context, initializers);
        }
    };
    return factory;
}
```