# Embedded Tomcat web query and strace with lstat() and stat() calls

Tags: java, performance, spring-mvc, tomcat

I make web-query https://domain/searchservice/api/v1.0/a535/suggestions
with strace and find API calls like next, where find:

```
stat("/tmp/tomcat-docbase.1677567135144838559.31583/searchservice/api/v1.0/a535/suggestions"
```

What is this call and is it possible do avoid stat() for every web-query ?

All calls here:

```
[pid 14787] <... lstat resumed> 0x7f708f0f4f00) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 14787] lstat("/tmp",  <unfinished ...>
[pid 14787] <... lstat resumed> {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
[pid 14787] lstat("/tmp/tomcat-docbase.1677567135144838559.31583",  <unfinished ...>
[pid 14787] <... lstat resumed> {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
[pid 14787] stat("/tmp/tomcat-docbase.1677567135144838559.31583/searchservice/api/v1.0/a535/suggestions",  <unfinished ...>
[pid 14787] <... stat resumed> 0x7f708f0f6fb0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 14787] futex(0x7f73b800e6cc, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, add question.

Comment: Let me guess - you're running Spring Boot? It may be misconfigured. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43089611/tmp-tomcat-docbase-is-always-created-with-a-spring-boot-jar-but-not-a-war)

Comment: Yes, you right - it's embedded Tomcat with Spring Boot

Comment: Your link about problem of creating temporary directory for docBase in /tmp every time when appliation running again. But my question about stat() - when every asked URI searched in file system.