# Invalid path of external Kafka keystore and truststore

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, apache-kafka

My app connects to Kafka topic and everything goes well in local environment when truststore and keystore are stored under classpath, but when I try to switch to Dockerized external environment and point to those files localized on a server, then the app crashes.

Snippet in a local environment where it works:

```
spring.kafka.ssl.trust-store-location=file:src/main/resources/keys/application.truststore.jks
spring.kafka.ssl.key-store-location=file:src/main/resources/keys/application.keystore.jks
```

Snippet of application.properties on a server side when the app is launched inside a docker container and does not work. Both keys are stored in `/deployment/keys` folder inside the container:

```
spring.kafka.ssl.trust-store-location=/deployment/keys/application.truststore.jks
spring.kafka.ssl.key-store-location=/deployment/keys/application.keystore.jks
```

The following java exception occurs:

```
NoSuchFileException: /tmp/tomcat-docbase.45456574985379.8080/deployment/keys/application.keystore.jks
```

So for an unknown reason Spring Boot inside Docker container adds the `/tmp/tomcat-docbase.45456574985379.8080/` prefix to the keystore and truststore location.

I have also tried:

```
spring.kafka.ssl.trust-store-location=file:/deployment/keys/application.truststore.jks
spring.kafka.ssl.key-store-location=file:/deployment/keys/application.keystore.jks
```

and

```
spring.kafka.ssl.trust-store-location=file:///deployment/keys/application.truststore.jks
spring.kafka.ssl.key-store-location=file:///deployment/keys/application.keystore.jks
```

but none of them seem to work. I would not like to change the code but what comes to my mind is to create a Properties object and create strings with those paths. Then inject them to the KafkaTemplate as a bean. However, I have not yet checked if this could help. Would rather focus just on adjusting application.properties file than correct the code. Could you please help me find the solution?

Comment: 1. confirm presence & find out correct path of the files *in docker* 2.refer to them in applicaiton.properties (3. for local/multiple environments: override properties/+use profiles)

Comment: All the points you listed are fulfilled for sure. Spring Boot just adds this weird prefix to the key paths as I wrote in the post.

Comment: humm..see [here1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11962) and [here2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43089611/592355)... possible workarounds: setting/involving `server.tomcat.basedir` and maybe [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11962#issuecomment-364087086) (create a "public" folder in .jar's directory)

Comment: Any update on this ?

Comment: Try something like "file://" (with to slashes) or give an absolute file path without "file://" prefix at all. Also, check if docker volume is correctly mapped if used.